# Forecasting each time series from a group of time series

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, facebook-prophet

I have a dataset that has multiple time series and I want my predictions on each of the time series in that group. Let me explain with an example

```
    Month StoreName Product Sales
    01/21     A      Pasta   100
    02/21     A      Pasta   70
    03/21     A      Pasta   140
    02/21     A      Rice    30
    03/21     A      Rice    10
    04/21     A      Rice    30
    03/21     B      pasta   200
    04/21     B      pasta   30
    01/21     B      Rice    120
    03/21     B      Rice    180
    04/21     B      Rice    100
```

Now, For a given StoreName and Product what will be the sales in the upcoming months. There are few things to be noted here.

1. Intermittent demand (example: missing sales in February for store B)
2. Encoding the categorical variables which have 200+ products, 200+ stores.
3. Time series model for each set. ([A, Pasta], [A, Rice], [B, Pasta], [B, Rice])

Is it possible to model multiple time series without looping because of high cardinality? Any sort of solution in python is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've explored [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/rsesha/multi-store-multi-item-with-automated-time-series)  but they've used for loop which is not apt in my case.

Comment: Post the code that you have so far. And you need to break up your question into several sub-questions, and post those instead of this one big question. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Sorry, @jsb I'm still in the analysis phase. Exploring  the approaches.

Comment: Good, keep it up. Post when you have some code and a well defined single problem.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the `statsmodels` package will have what you're looking for, which appears to be predicting a numeric value based on a mix of other numeric and categorical predictor variables. You have time series data which makes this a little trickier, but as a first exploration you could encode the month of the year as it's own column, then use `statsmodels` ordinary least squares model to get started with analysis:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

lm = smf.ols(formula='Sales ~ Month + Storename + Product', data=df)
residuals = lm.fit()
print(residuals.summary())
```

That will give you a nice regression table like the following, and then you can continue exploring and better incorporating the timeseries element of your data from there.

```
 OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                Sales   R-squared:                       0.338
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.287
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     6.636
Date:                Thu, 25 Mar 2021   Prob (F-statistic):           1.07e-05
Time:                        19:37:47   Log-Likelihood:                -375.30
No. Observations:                  85   AIC:                             764.6
Df Residuals:                      78   BIC:                             781.7
Df Model:                           6                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      38.6517      9.456      4.087      0.000      19.826      57.478
Product        -15.4278     9.727     -1.586      0.117     -34.793       3.938
StoreName      -10.0170     9.260     -1.082      0.283     -28.453       8.419
Month          -4.5483      7.279     -0.625      0.534     -19.039       9.943

========================================================================
```

For more info, I expect the stat models documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/example_formulas.html) and [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/variance_components.html) will get you off on a good start.

Another class of models to look into are [ARIMA models](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html), though you need to make sure your data is stationary and it's harder to get in and do exploratory analysis in <5mins with ARIMA models.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. I will surely explore the links you've shared. If possible, Can you be a bit specific on how to achieve this using ARIMA Models?

Comment: [This article](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm) should help you get started making your data stationary. Once it's stationary, you can start using the arima models off the shelf from `statsmodels`.

Comment: I have accepted the answer to the other question. but, the answer to this question has helped me in moving a step forward but I can't say that this is the exact answer. So, I have upvoted it but with lack of reputation, you couldn't see the upvote.

Comment: @BLimitless hi have you got your answer can you reply to your own question i am looking for something similar to your use case thanks